# What percentage of integers has this form?

Tags: number-theory

Consider integers of the form:

$344\cdot s + 22919\cdot r$.

My questions are:

1 - what percentage of integers have this form if $r$ and $s$ are allowed only to be positive.

2- what percentage of integers have this form if $r$ and $s$ are allowed to be $\in Z$, so also negative or zero.

Is brute force approach with a computer useful to solve this problem?

Comment: Another random looking question about $344$ from a new account.

Comment: This is a statistical question

Comment: No, it is not.  There is no probability involved here.

Comment: Ok not all the integers have this form, so I wonder what percentage of integers have this form

Comment: @lulu what do you mean "another question"? Is someone spamming questions based on the number 344?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan  Yes.  this all has to do with a class of primes that supposedly has some structure to them, though no structure has been demonstrated. The original user who was pushing this agenda was suspended for using sock puppet accounts, like this one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that answers 2, not 1.

Comment: @lulu interesting. Is there a meta post on the recent occurings?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I don't know.  To your last comment, the answers for $1$ and $2$ are the same.  Requiring positivity just blocks out a finite list of terms, see [Frobenius Coins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde yes answer 2, but not 1

Comment: @lulu I will keep you informed if I find any 344 related posts.

Comment: @lulu at least primes of that class with exponent multiple of 43 do have a structure, but to demonstrate it it's too hard

Comment: @lulu the exponents multiple of 86 of that class of prime have all the form 344+2236x. Obviously I have no demonstation

Answer (score 1):

Since $\gcd(344,\,22919)=43$, only multiples of $43$ have the desired form. For each version of your question, [all sufficiently large positive multiples of $43$ qualify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_=_2). So a proportion $1/86$ of integers qualify for version 1, if we modify the definition of natural density to cover integers of arbitrary sign in the obvious way ($n\to\infty$ limit of the proportion of successes among integers of modulus $\le n$). For version 2, it becomes $1/43$. I'll leave conversions to percentages to you.